# What is the meaning of hostless in terms of IC/Controllers/SOCs?

Tags: terminology

The question is specific to [QCA4020](https://createpoint.qti.qualcomm.com/search/contentdocument/stream/259141?refererRoute=search%2FsearchArgs%2Fq%7C%7Cqca4020%7C%7Cstart%7C%7C2%7C%7Crows%7C%7C10%7C%7CsortField%7C%7Cscore%7C%7CsortOrder%7C%7Cdesc&dcn=80-Y9381-14&currentPage=3&itemTotalIndex=22)(You may not be able to access it!).There are certain IC's that claim to be hostless, and to my understanding that is it doesn't need a master to control them. But this specific is SOC itself, so what is the point of calling it hostless?

Comment: Well, you've restricted answers to only those able to login with a registered Email or qualpass username and that isn't much use I would say. Speak with Qualcomm.

Comment: @Andyaka I see. After posting the question I don't really feel that it matters whether they call it hostless or not,to me at least. That discussion doesn't seem worth the time. But a question out of curiosity , **How do I know if it is ok to download the pdf and share link after putting it on dropbox to ask a question here?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because restricted answers to only those able to login with a registered Email or qualpass username

Comment: @MaNyYaCk to answer the document sharing rights question, if you obtained the document through something more restricted than by clicking on some link from the publicly accessible internet, you are most certainly not allowed to share it. In fact, even if it is a public document, sometimes, the license forbids you to distribute it yourself, and you can only provide a link to the manufacturer-hosted document (e.g. see [TI copyright terms](http://www.ti.com/corp/docs/legal/copyright.shtml) that apply to datasheets: you can keep the documents for your own usage, but not distribute it).

Comment: @dim what if you obtained the link through being signed on, but the document is available through deep-linking (fairly common)? A lot of SoC documents require an NDA to be signed and that's 100% clear (in legalese, but clear enough), but things may be a bit more gray in the middle.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany If the link only works while logged on as a specific user on the site, you can assume you won't be allowed to share it. Same if the link is public, but has only been given to you once you signed something or registered through whatever means. Even more so if the document is not visible by any search engine. Actually, it is safer to assume that you're not allowed to redistribute any document ever, even if it is fully public, as the TI terms linked above demonstrated. In any case, there should be some document explaining the specific terms of use for the manufacturer.

Comment: @dim Agree that's the safest course, especially for those of us subject to draconian laws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://www.qualcomm.com/media/documents/files/qca402x-product-brief.pdf) is a product brief.

"Hostless" refers an IoT platform that uses the SoC without an external 
microcontroller. This SoC has an ARM Cortex-M4F for running application programs.

> **Application CPU** Arm Cortex-M4F @ up to 128MHz
>   32KB- L1 cache controller, XIP from external S-flash
>   Internal Memory: 300+KB RAM reserved for applications
>
> **Connectivity/System CPU** Dedicated processor for Bluetooth LE LC and 15.4 MAC
>   Dedicated processor for 802.11 a/b/g/n
>   Isolated Memory: RAM, ROM

From a press release for the [QCA4010](https://www.qualcomm.com/news/releases/2016/05/31/qualcomm-brings-new-wi-fi-solution-and-software-ecosystem-support-enhance):

> Using SX-ULPGN’s hostless mode, device manufacturers can develop complete IoT/IoE solutions with Wi-Fi connectivity without an external MCU at a cost effective price point. Using our UART AT command option, they can quickly add a serial-to-Wi-Fi converter for existing MCU based designs without porting any host driver.”